# fb.login run dialog in the background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

in order to check if the user has provided all the permissions i need for my app,  I do it so:

```
/*Solo hacemos la peticion si el checkbox estaba desmarcado. Nota: esta funcion asume que solo hay un checkbox en el dom*/
if($('input:checkbox').prop('checked')){
    FB.login(function(response){
             console.log(response.status);
            if (response.status == 'connected') {
            hi   /* Entonces listo */
            }else{
                 /* Entonces cancelamos el checkbox */
                 $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
            }
    }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });
}
```

This way:

- if user did it allready: a popup is opened for less than a second
- if user didnt yet: the permission dialog is shown

Question is: how can i prevent the dialog to be opened (maybe running it in the background) in the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot stop a popup when you use `FB.login`.

Either use a server side authentication or use `FB.getLoginStatus` to prevent popup in first case.

> FB.getLoginStatus allows you to determine if a user is logged in to
>   Facebook and has authenticated your app

Refer [Facebook docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

A snippet from the above reference link,

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

This is what you need.

**Edit:** (after OP's comment)

May be facebook is caching old result. 
From the same link I mentioned above,

> **Roundtrips to Facebook's servers**
>
> To improve the performace of your application, not every call to check
>   the status of the user will result in request to Facebook's servers.
>   Where possible, the response is cached. The first time in the current
>   browser session that FB.getLoginStatus is called, or the JD SDK is
>   init'd with status: true, the response object will be cached by the
>   SDK. Subsequent calls to FB.getLoginStatus will return data from this
>   cached response.
>
> This can cause problems where the user has logged into (or out of)
>   Facebook since the last full session lookup, or if the user has
>   removed your application in their account settings.
>
> To get around this, you call FB.getLoginStatus with the second
>   parameter set to true to force a roundtrip to Facebook - effectively
>   refreshing the cache of the response object.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      // this will be called when the roundtrip to Facebook has completed
    }, true);
```

> If you call FB.getLoginStatus on every page load, be careful not to
>   set this parameter for each as it will significantly increase the
>   number of requests to Facebook's servers, and thus decrease the
>   performace of your application.

Comment: This also, is allways 'connected' no matter what the user does (accept, ommit or close the Facebook request)

Comment: Are you sure ? Can you put all of your code, so we can point out the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The facebook sdk `login()` function opens a pop up by default, as you can read in the [Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/).

so that's not the way you wanna go.
There are 2 simillar question that you might find it's info useful.

Try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048385/facebook-js-sdk-check-permissions-before-login-popup) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125320/facebook-login-without-pop-up).